# In rust how to modify a boxed function and assign it back?

Tags: rust

Example:

```rust
struct S<T> {
  f: Box<dyn Fn(T)>,
}

impl<T> S<T> {
  fn test(mut self) {
    let f = self.f;
    let f = Box::new(move |t| f(t));
    self.f = f;
  }
}
```

In the `test` function, I want to modify the function and assign it back to `self.f`.

However, the compiler said `` the parameter type `T` may not live long enough `` and `` consider adding an explicit lifetime bound: `: 'static` ``  to `T`.

Why there is such a requirement? Can I modify the boxed function and assign it back without adding `'static` to `T`?

Comment: [shorter reproducable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f5ffee73f71e938e796bf2f45a98d147)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes, in certain cases, if a trait object has no lifetime bounds, its lifetime becomes `'static`, which is probably what happens here. To prevent this, the lifetime should be explicitly declared: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3509dce4c32cd6e35da69b2b604437ef))

```rust
struct S<'a, T: 'a> {
  f: Box<dyn Fn(T) + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> S<'a, T> {
  fn test(mut self) {
    let f = self.f;
    let f = Box::new(move |t| f(t));
    self.f = f;
  }
}
```